# In cardview with radiogroup in list some radio buttons are already checked

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-cardview, android-radiogroup

I had created cardview with radio group in android here i am making student attendence taker system ,i had already made backend part and student list is coming correctly and showing in cards but problem is at time of present, or absent marking of student , i had used radiogroup with 4 radio button in each card . But some radio buttons are already been checked and when i am scrolling then checked position of radio button is also changing .:-
code for every single card is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"

    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEmailId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
            android:text="email"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/rg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="A"
            android:checked="false">


        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/chkSelected2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:text="P"
            android:checked="false">


        </RadioButton>

</RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and code for checkboxsample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check All"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
            android:id="@+id/btnCheckAll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear All"
            android:id="@+id/btnClearAll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvCheckBox"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

code for activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Show Selected"
        android:background="#00796B" 
        android:textColor="@color/TextPrimaryColor"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

code for student.java

```
package com.example.administrator.cardviewcheckbok;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    private String emailId;

    private boolean isSelected;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String name, String emailId) {

        this.name = name;
        this.emailId = emailId;

    }

    public Student(String name, String emailId, boolean isSelected) {

        this.name = name;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

}
```

code for cardviewdataadapter.java

```
package com.example.administrator.cardviewcheckbok;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class CardViewDataAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Student> stList;

    public CardViewDataAdapter(List<Student> students) {
        this.stList = students;

    }

    // Create new views
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
            int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.cardview_row, null);

        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        final int pos = position;

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(stList.get(position).getName());

        viewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(stList.get(position).getEmailId());

        viewHolder.chkSelected.setSelected(stList.get(position).isSelected());

        viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));
////new checkselected2

        viewHolder.chkSelected2.setSelected(stList.get(position).isSelected());

        viewHolder.chkSelected2.setTag(stList.get(position));

viewHolder.checkrgg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RadioGroup rgg=(RadioGroup)v;
int selbutid=rgg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    RadioButton rb= (RadioButton) rgg.getChildAt(selbutid);
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),""+rb.getText()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});

        viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioButton cb = (RadioButton) v;

                Student contact = (Student) cb.getTag();

                contact.setSelected(cb.isSelected());
                stList.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isSelected());

    /*          Toast.makeText(
                        v.getContext(),
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + "" + pos + cb + " is "
                                + cb.isSelected(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    */
                    }

            });


        viewHolder.chkSelected2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioButton cb = (RadioButton) v;

                Student contact = (Student) cb.getTag();

                contact.setSelected(cb.isSelected());
                stList.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isSelected());
/*
                Toast.makeText(
                        v.getContext(),
                        "2222222Clicked on Checkbox: "+""+pos +cb + " is "
                                + cb.isSelected(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                */
                    }
        });



    }

    // Return the size arraylist
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final RadioGroup checkrgg;
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvEmailId;

        public RadioButton chkSelected,chkSelected2;

        public Student singlestudent;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            tvName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

            tvEmailId = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
            chkSelected = (RadioButton) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);

            ///here putted code
            chkSelected2 = (RadioButton) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.chkSelected2);
////
            checkrgg=(RadioGroup)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rg);

        }

    }

    // method to access in activity after updating selection
    public List<Student> getStudentist() {
        return stList;
    }

}
```

code for cardviewactivity.java

```
package com.example.administrator.cardviewcheckbok;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CardViewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private List<Student> studentList;

    private Button btnSelection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        btnSelection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);

        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
            Student st = new Student("Student " + i, "androidstudent" + i
                    + "@gmail.com", false);

            studentList.add(st);
        }

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Android Students");

        }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // create an Object for Adapter
        mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(studentList);

        // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data = "";
                List<Student> stList = ((CardViewDataAdapter) mAdapter)
                        .getStudentist();

                for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                    Student singleStudent = stList.get(i);
                    if (singleStudent.isSelected() == true) {

                        data = data + "\n" + singleStudent.getName().toString();
                        /*
                         * Toast.makeText( CardViewActivity.this, " " +
                         * singleStudent.getName() + " " +
                         * singleStudent.getEmailId() + " " +
                         * singleStudent.isSelected(),
                         * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         */

                ////
                                                }

                }

                Toast.makeText(CardViewActivity.this,
                        "Selected Students: \n" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Please these is big problematic issue . Actually if we do it by using list then also same error comes , so want help from community to please give some suggestion on these issue of  . "card view with radio group in list"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code:

Please look on "RecyclerViewAdapter.java", "onBindViewHolder" event.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Book> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getNextItems();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, this, recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        adapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                Log.i("LoadMore", "onLoadMore called");
                //add progress item
                data.add(null);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Log.i("LoadMore", "Loading new data... (" + 10 + ") posts");
                //remove progress item
                data.remove(data.size() - 1);

                getNextItems();

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //add items one by one

                adapter.setLoaded();
            }
        });

    }

    private void getNextItems() {
        int itemCount = data.size();
        for (int i = itemCount; i <= itemCount + 10; i++) {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.title = "Title " + i;
            book.author = "Author " + i;
            book.description = "Description " + i;
            book.status = -1;
            data.add(book);
        }
    }

}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private List<Book> dataSet;
    private Context context;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 1;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> status;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Book> data, Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.context = context;
        status = new ArrayMap<>();
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    loading = true;
                    // End has been reached
                    // Do something
                    Log.i("AdapterScrolled", "onScrolled: End reached");
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView description;
        TextView title;
        TextView author;
        ImageView profilePic;
        RadioGroup radioGroup;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.profilePic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            this.description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            radioGroup = (RadioGroup) itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return dataSet.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.book_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.progress_bar_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
//                Binding Views...

            Book book = dataSet.get(position);
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).profilePic.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.empty_user));
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).title.setText(book.title);
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).author.setText(book.author);
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).description.setText(book.description);

            final RadioGroup radioGroup = ((MyViewHolder) holder).radioGroup;
            radioGroup.setTag(book);
            radioGroup.clearCheck();
            final RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.low);
            final RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.medium);
            final RadioButton radioButton3 = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.high);

            int value = book.status;
            if (value == 0) {
                radioButton1.setChecked(true);
            } else if (value == 1) {
                radioButton2.setChecked(true);
            } else if (value == 2) {
                radioButton3.setChecked(true);
            }

            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    Book tagBook = (Book) radioGroup.getTag();
                    if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {
                        tagBook.status = 0;
                    } else if (radioButton2.isChecked()) {
                        tagBook.status = 1;
                    } else if (radioButton3.isChecked()) {
                        tagBook.status = 2;
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
        void onLoadMore();
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        }
    }
}
```

Book.java

```
public class Book {
    String title;
    String author;
    String description;
    int status = -1;
}
```

book_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/book_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/low"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Low" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/high"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="High" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```